# How can i make a image selection field with FLUX that is like the TYPO3-native image content type?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.1.x, flux, fedext

Is it possible to create a image selection field with [Flux/Fluid FlexForms](https://fedext.net/viewhelpers/flux.html) like the default [TYPO3-Image-ContentElement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4EH6.png)?

And if yes, how?

I could only create a [input field (with wizard)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4EH6.png) that links to the files table. This is the code:

```
<flux:flexform.field.input name="file" eval="trim">
    <flux:flexform.field.wizard.link allowedExtensions="jpg,jpeg,png,gif"/>
</flux:flexform.field.input>
```

But i want it like the [TYPO3-Image-ContentElement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4EH6.png) with thumbnail, filename etc..

[image: native TYPO3 6.1 image selection]
[image: this is how my fluid image field looks like]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature has been added to the current flux master on [github](https://github.com/FluidTYPO3/flux).

You can use it like this:

```xml
<flux:flexform.field.inline.fal name="myimage"
     multiple="TRUE" maxItems="5"
     enabledControls="{info:1,new:1,dragdrop:1,sort:1,hide:1}"/>
```

Comment: for the enabledControls to work, you have to supply them as integers. {info: 1, new: 0, dragdrop: 1, ... }

Comment: It's `<flux:field.inline.fal>` now.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe someone wants the solution with the current version of flux (7.4.0):

Make the Backend-Field:

```
<flux:field.inline.fal name="bild" showThumbs="true" allowedExtensions="'gif,jpg,jpeg,tif,tiff,bmp,pcx,tga,png,pdf,ai,svg'" maxItems="1" required="true" />
```

Call the Image:

```
{v:content.resources.fal(field: 'bild') -> v:iterator.first() -> v:variable.set(name: 'bild')}
    <f:image treatIdAsReference="1" src="{bild.id}" title="{bild.title}" alt="{bild.alternative}" maxWidth="80" maxHeight="50" crop="{bild.crop}"/>
```

Full code for my content-element:

```
<f:layout name="Content"/>

<f:section name="Configuration">
    <flux:form id="footerbild" options="{group: 'FeWo-Seiteninhalte'}">

        <flux:field.inline.fal name="bild" showThumbs="true" allowedExtensions="'gif,jpg,jpeg,tif,tiff,bmp,pcx,tga,png,pdf,ai,svg'" maxItems="1" required="true" />

    </flux:form>
</f:section>

<f:section name="Preview">

    {v:content.resources.fal(field: 'bild') -> v:iterator.first() -> v:variable.set(name: 'bild')}
    <f:image treatIdAsReference="1" src="{bild.id}" title="{bild.title}" alt="{bild.alternative}" maxWidth="80" maxHeight="50" crop="{bild.crop}"/>

</f:section>


<f:section name="Main">

    {v:content.resources.fal(field: 'bild') -> v:iterator.first() -> v:variable.set(name: 'bild')}
    <f:image class="img-responsive" treatIdAsReference="1" src="{bild.id}" title="{bild.title}" alt="{bild.alternative}" crop="{bild.crop}"/>

</f:section>
```

This does the following in preview:

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VR730.png)

And this in backend plugin:

[Plugin-view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLxWe.png)

It supports Image-Upload, image-crop with the built-in editor etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only one way at the moment - to create a new custom field with custom rendering and logic. It's preferable to use the Core to create fields.

You could check the method in the sources of `flux` extension. Check how classes and wizards are made.

There is similar problem on 4.5.x LTS for DAM support.

Comment: Yes you are right - the table structure of FAL is similar to DAM.
But i think it might be possible to create a native like field with flexform.field.inline (IRRE Records). I will wait, maybe someone else has a solution..

https://fedext.net/viewhelpers/flux/Flexform/Field/InlineViewHelper.html

Comment: That will be great to find more simple solution.

Comment: I would - like Benjamin suggests - try my way with the `flux:flexform.field.inline` ViewHelper. It should allow you sufficient control to create new DAM-relation records.

Comment: Here is the field configuration needed:
http://wiki.typo3.org/File_Abstraction_Layer#TCA
But there are some configuration values flux seems to be missing:
- foreign_match_fields
- foreign_selector_fieldTcaOverride
- filter

I will keep this question up to date with my progress ..

Comment: @Benjamin You could make a custom field, which will add configuration You need. Look how File field is defined, in flux, You could create a Media field with similar properties. Only 2 files needed to achieve the goal, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I did a viewHelper with flux 6.0.1 to have the same media field.

But i test the version from github and mine and we have the same problem : the copy/paste of a content with this type of field don't copy the media. The record from the table sys_file is not copied.

I think typo3 team have the same problem and it's why they don't use this type of field in the "text image" and "image" contents

Answer (score 0):

How about this:
Not really FAL support but it works and no file numbers are shown. Depends on the upload-Folder.

```
<flux:flexform.sheet name="slider" label="Slider Bilder - Startseite">
  <flux:flexform.section name="sliderImagges">
    <flux:flexform.object name="image" >
      <flux:flexform.field.input name="linkTitle" label="Titel" /> 
        <flux:flexform.field.file name="image" label="Bild"
      uploadFolder="uploads/pics/"
      validate="trim" size="1" showThumbs="1"
      internalType="file" allowed="jpg,png,gif" />
        <flux:flexform.field.input name="url" label="Ziel des Links">
    <flux:flexform.field.wizard.link activeTab="page" />
      </flux:flexform.field.input>
    </flux:flexform.object>
  </flux:flexform.section>
</flux:flexform.sheet>
```